# Different actions equivalence in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, action

I started reading up on the different actions that appear in GR. I have come across two:

1. When looking at geodesics I found: 
   $$S=\int \sqrt{-g_{\mu \nu} \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda} \frac{dx^\nu}{d\lambda}}d\lambda$$
   (I have also seen this with a coefficient of $-mc$)

   2. When actually looking for Action in general relativity I came across the Einstein-Hilbert action: 
      $$S=\int \{\frac{1}{2\kappa} (R-2 \Lambda)+L_M\} \sqrt{-g}d^4x$$

Why do we have two different types or is there an equivalence between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first action is the action of a point particle. The second is the action of the gravitational field itself. You can easily use the two of them together to get both the geodesic equation and the Einstein Field equations with a point particle as its source (in this case, you will have $L_M = \sqrt{-g_{\mu\nu} \dot{x}^\mu \dot{x}^\nu }$).